# Find and replace using regular expressions in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have to make changes to URL's in a couple of notepad files. I was hoping if this could be done using regular expressions.

The URL's are in the following structure,

```
/web/20120730114452im_/hxxp://mysite1.com
/web/20120730114453im_/hxxp://mysite2.com
/web/20120730114454im_/hxxp://mysite3.com
/web/20120730114454im_/hxxp://mysite4.com
```

I have to remove the part before the hxxp so what remains after the search and replace is,

```
hxxp://mysite1.com
hxxp://mysite2.com
hxxp://mysite3.com
hxxp://mysite4.com
```

What is the regular expression I need to use to get the desired result ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is the part before `hxxp` always in the same format of `/` then `web` then `/`, then numbers, then `im_/`?

Comment: Yes, everything except the number remains the same.

Comment: did u tried my solution? update me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, as per your confirmation, a proper regex that won't match too much would be this:

```
/web/[0-9]+im_/
```

Where `[0-9]+` will match any amount of numbers.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/uF7mH7).

Don't forget to check the 'regular expression' checkbox in the Find/Replace dialog box.

Comment: That worked!! Thanks a lot Jerry, you've saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

USE THIS,

```
FIND:      [ a-z 0-9 _ / ]+/hxxp
REPLACE:   hxxp
```

Comment: Yes, I did. However it matched a lot of other things apart from what I was looking for. Anyways no problem, Jerry's answers worked for me. Thanks a lot for taking time to help me out.